# How to get Values of Response ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs

Hey guys im pretty new in developing with react.

I got some problems to fetch data from my json response

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9000/test')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data.name);
    console.log(response.name)
});
```

```
{
    "name": "mkyong",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
       "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
       "city": "New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
    {
       "type": "home",
       "number": "111 111-1111"
    },
    {
       "type": "fax",
       "number": "222 222-2222"
    }
   ]
}
```

The console shows me undefined.
Whats the problem why i cant get the data via plain js?

Comment: Did u checked the response ? Check response first, then try to access its objects.

Comment: i already checked the response . Console displays a valid json!

Comment: Can you send the json ?

Comment: console.log(response.data) -> {
      "name": "mkyong",
      "age": 30,
      "address": {
        "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
        "city": "New York"
      },
      "phoneNumber": [
      {
        "type": "home",
        "number": "111 111-1111"
      },
      {
        "type": "fax",
        "number": "222 222-2222"
      }
      ]
    }

Comment: Just console.log(response.name). It should print the correct output. If not, please check for the response(whether its a strong or object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well because the response of an axios call is a string, so you have to `parse` it first,

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9000/test')
   .then(function (response) {
         const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
         console.log(parsedResponse.name));
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, something like this worked:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9000/test')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data['name']);
});
```

There may be different levels of the json tree, so in my case I first tried displaying just response.data to see what's inside & got to the element this way.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure its not

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9000/test')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response['data'][name]);
    console.log(response[name])
});
```

Comment: tried and noting realy changes expect for more errors